# How do I pull a single value from every row in a csv?

Tags: awk, grep, csv

I have a large amount of data formatted like this:

```
value1,value2,value3
value1,value2,value3
value1,value2,value3
etc..
```

I want to know how to pull only value2 from every row and output that result. I'm assuming I would use awk in some way?

Comment: Does any of the first two columns contain embedded commas or newlines (which is allowed in CSV files)?

Comment: Is "value2" chosen because of its position or because of its value?

Comment: There are no embedded commas or new lines, its chosen because of its position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' file
```

or `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f2 file
```

or `csvcut`

```
csvcut -H -c 2 f | tail -n+2
```

`csvcut` has the benefit that it also works if you have the delimiter inside the values, e.g.: `value1,"value2,3",value4`.